# Android TimePicker with custom title

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

I have TimePicker in pop up dialog.. 
here is the code..

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
{
    switch (id) 
    {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        // set time picker as current time
        final TimePickerDialog tmp = new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute, true);
        tmp.setTitle("Helo");
        tmp.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
            {
                tmp.setTitle("Hello");

                return false;
            }
        });

        return tmp;

    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm using example from here.. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-time-picker-example/

now I wan to remove title from dialog.. and set my custom title.. in this case I'm using
timepicker.setTitle("Hello"); but when I'm changing values of timepicker.. title automatically changing to values of time.. how can I maintain title? or detect time changes..? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass OnTimeSetListener in your TimePickerDialog() constructor and listen to time changes by overriding onTimeSet() method.

```
OnTimeSetListener listener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
             mDialog.setTitle("Hello");
            }
        };
```

Comment: What set button do you imply? What android version do you use?

Comment: It looks like they removed this functionality in one of the the latest release. To answer your question you should extend TimePickerDialog class, override onTimeChanged() method and leave it empty.

Comment: now I'm using this timepickerdialog.setCustomTitle(myTextView);

Comment: @Henrik i am unable to find this timepickerdialog.setCustomTitle()

and where should i set title on onTimeSet or onTimeChanged